# How can I add my own style to gmap [google_map_flutter plugin]

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add my own style to the GoogleMap Widget, after have used https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/ to generate the json corresponding to what I want.

I've looked into the google_map_flutter plugin to see any properties I could overwrite to add my style but didn't find any.

Some more experienced users of flutter may have and idea of where to begin, I would greatly appreciate the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the JSON and  and save the file in `txt` format.
Add this file to the assets of your Flutter project, by placing it in your assets folder and specifying it in your `pubspec.yaml`

```
 flutter:  
  assets:
    - assets/map_style.txt
```

In the State class where your GoogleMap widget resides, add the following import statement:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
```

And add a field that will represent your style in String format:

```
String _mapStyle;
```

We can now load the txt file as a String and feed it to the _mapStyle field. We do this from within the `initState` method of the State class:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  rootBundle.loadString('assets/map_style.txt').then((string) {
    _mapStyle = string;
  });
}
```

Now when you initialize the `GoogleMap` widget and its corresponding `GoogleMapController,` set the style as follows:

```
GoogleMapController mapController;
GoogleMap(
  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    mapController.setMapStyle(_mapStyle);
  }
```

And you’re done! The map will now load your custom style and you can simply edit the style from within map_style.txt when needed.
**approach 2**

```
GoogleMapController mapController;
void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
    mapController.setMapStyle('[{"featureType": "all","stylers": [{ "color": "#C0C0C0" }]},{"featureType": "road.arterial","elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{ "color": "#CCFFFF" }]},{"featureType": "landscape","elementType": "labels","stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]}]');
  }
);
```

Comment: i was not using the latest version of the plugin (## 0.5.16 added support for map styling ). It works now ! thanks a lot